# SHA-1 keeps changing every couple of days

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-maps-v2, sha

I'm building an Android app based on `google maps V2 api`, using the api console. To do that I need to generate a key using my `SHA-1` that's generated through the debug `keystore` locally. Only then I get the desired key which I put in my Android Manifest, but every now and then it doesn't work because my `SHA-1` have changed so I need to replace the old one with the new.

Any chance to make it stay the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same keystore file, the SHA-1 fingerprint should not be changing. You may need to look into to whether you are creating/deleting debug keystore files or perhaps the expiration on it has been set to be only a few days.

To better avoid the issue, you should [generate](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) your own keystore file specifically for your application. You can use the newly generate keystore file to build the application and *only* that application. No other application should use that keystore file and the application you're working on should only use that keystore file.

Comment: I guess somehow it got deleted. From now on I'll use different keystore for each app. Thanks !